# Boolean Simplification (1.2)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm going to attempt to ask a question again. I'm new to this site and I think that this site could be useful to me through out the 4 years in University for me. Can you tell me whether I'm going the right direction with this simplification

I came across a Boolean Simplifcation question and I would like your help.

A'BC'D' + AB'C'D' + AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABCD'
= A'BC'D' + AB'D' (C'+ C) + ABC'D + ABCD'
= A'BC'D' + AB'D' + ABC'D + ABCD'

A'BC'D' + AB'D' + ABC'D + ABCD'
AB(C'D + CD')
AB(1.D + 1.D')
AB(D + D')
AB(1)
AB

A'BC'D + AB'D' + AB
D(A'BC' + AB')
= D (A⊕B + C)
= D + C' + A⊕B + AB

Comment: You need to do some work. Have you tried factoring minterms that share variables. There is no magic here, just work.

Comment: I was asked to simplify the minterm, nothing about factoring, I'm not sure!

Comment: Try factoring into groups of the form $(\cdots)D + (\cdots )D'$ where the terms inside the brackets have no $D,D'$. I haven't solved the problem, but this is how I would start.

Comment: I should factoring into group from the start of the expression? And the terms inside the brackets, use boolean laws to simplify them?

Comment: That would be a good start. There is no recipe, you need to try different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A'BC'D'+AB'C'D'+AB'CD'+ABC'D+ABCD' =$ (use Adjacency to combine 2nd and 3rd as well as 3rd and 5th)

$A'BC'D'+ AB'D' + ACD' + ABC'D =$ (use Distribution to combine 1st and 4th as wel as 2nd and third)

$BC'(A'D'+AD) + AD'(B'+C) =$ (use XOR)

$BC'(A \bigoplus D') + AD'(B'+C)$

That's about as simple as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If we want a minimal sum of products (without using XOR), then a Karnaugh map shows that the best we can do is simplify from $5$ to $3$:
\begin{align*}
&A'BC'D' + AB'C'D' + AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABCD \\
&= A'BC'D' + AB'D'(C' + C) + ABD(C' + C) \\
&= A'BC'D' + AB'D' + ABD \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the help, Adriano. I appreciate it. 

Question: using XOR wouldn't make sense in this expression, or?

Comment: And the laws that you used to simplify the expression were just the "Distributive law" right?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add " ' " on the last variable, last set, I've edited the first expression. Could you re-check that? I would appreciate it VERY MUCH.